# What is best tool/framework for android app testing for developer?

Tags: android

I want to test my app after development, i test it manually,But what is the best tool for do a automation testing, so that i can make sure that app has been tested enough before release.

Comment: Android Studio has support for Espresso for UI testing, and you can also configure JUnit for unit testing. Please check out the following tutorial: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-testing/index.html#0 please note that in order to make your code testable, you need to ensure that your logic is properly separated and actually testable.

Answer (score 2):

**This is a wide topic**
1)if you want to replicate random clicks->use monkey runner
2)To to automation testing on UI->expresso,Mockito are quite good and popular
3)To test java code->junit